# The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName (null) for entityClass

Tags: java, benchmarking, optaplanner

I want to do a benchmark but it returns this exception after benchmark start. I saw a topic about this but it is about with EntitySelectorConfig but this is about ValueSelectorConfig and i couldn't find the solution in other benchmark.xml files. This is more important for me if anyone can help me this would be very good thing for me. Thanks in advance

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config (ValueSelectorConfig(null)) has no configured variableName (null) for entityClass (class org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.domain.Action) and because there are multiple variableNames ([employee, machine, period]), it can not be deduced automatically.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.AbstractConfig.deduceVariableDescriptor(AbstractConfig.java:114) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.value.ValueSelectorConfig.buildValueSelector(ValueSelectorConfig.java:273) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.PillarChangeMoveSelectorConfig.buildBaseMoveSelector(PillarChangeMoveSelectorConfig.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:194) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSelectorConfig.buildBaseMoveSelector(UnionMoveSelectorConfig.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.MoveSelectorConfig.buildMoveSelector(MoveSelectorConfig.java:194) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildMoveSelector(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:237) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildDecider(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildPhase(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:114) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildPhase(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildPhaseList(SolverConfig.java:297) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:233) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

And My benchmark.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark>
    <benchmarkDirectory>local/data/opnext</benchmarkDirectory>
    <parallelBenchmarkCount>AUTO</parallelBenchmarkCount>

    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <problemBenchmarks>
            <xStreamAnnotatedClass>org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.domain.Solution</xStreamAnnotatedClass>

            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/96time-60action.xml</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/96time-240action.xml</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/96time-400action.xml</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/2880time-40action.xml</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/2880time-240action.xml</inputSolutionFile>
            <inputSolutionFile>data/opnext/solved/2880time-480action.xml</inputSolutionFile>

            <problemStatisticType>BEST_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
            <problemStatisticType>STEP_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
            <problemStatisticType>SCORE_CALCULATION_SPEED</problemStatisticType>
            <problemStatisticType>BEST_SOLUTION_MUTATION</problemStatisticType>
            <problemStatisticType>MOVE_COUNT_PER_STEP</problemStatisticType>
            <problemStatisticType>MEMORY_USE</problemStatisticType>

            <singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_BEST_SCORE</singleStatisticType>
            <singleStatisticType>CONSTRAINT_MATCH_TOTAL_STEP_SCORE</singleStatisticType>
            <singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_BEST_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>
            <singleStatisticType>PICKED_MOVE_TYPE_STEP_SCORE_DIFF</singleStatisticType>
        </problemBenchmarks>

        <solver>
            <solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.domain.Solution</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.domain.Action</entityClass>
            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/opnext/solver/iskoTaskAssigningScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>
            <termination>
                <minutesSpentLimit>15</minutesSpentLimit>
            </termination>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
            <localSearch>
                <unionMoveSelector>
                    <changeMoveSelector/>
                    <swapMoveSelector>
                        <filterClass>org.optaplanner.examples.opnext.solver.move.DifferentActionSwapMoveFilter</filterClass>
                    </swapMoveSelector>
                </unionMoveSelector>

                <acceptor>
                    <lateAcceptanceSize>600</lateAcceptanceSize>
                </acceptor>
                <forager>
                    <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
                </forager>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>


    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>First Fit</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>First Fit Decreasing</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>

    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Tabu Search</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
            <localSearch>
                <unionMoveSelector>
                    <changeMoveSelector/>
                    <swapMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarChangeMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarSwapMoveSelector/>
                </unionMoveSelector>
                <acceptor>
                    <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
                </acceptor>
                <forager>
                    <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
                </forager>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Simulated Annealing</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
            <localSearch>
                <unionMoveSelector>
                    <changeMoveSelector/>
                    <swapMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarChangeMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarSwapMoveSelector/>
                </unionMoveSelector>
                <acceptor>
                    <simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>0hard/400soft</simulatedAnnealingStartingTemperature>
                </acceptor>
                <forager>
                    <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
                </forager>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
    <solverBenchmark>
        <name>Late Acceptance</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
            <localSearch>
                <unionMoveSelector>
                    <changeMoveSelector/>
                    <swapMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarChangeMoveSelector/>
                    <pillarSwapMoveSelector/>
                </unionMoveSelector>
                <acceptor>
                    <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
                </acceptor>
                <forager>
                    <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
                </forager>
            </localSearch>
        </solver>
    </solverBenchmark>
</plannerBenchmark>
```

And If you can give a little detail about benchmark it would be nice too.

Comment: It would indeed be nice if that error message also stated the type of move selector this is happening for, although the stacktrace does: `PillarChangeMoveSelectorConfig`.

Comment: so should i configure a PillarChangeMoveSelectorConfig ?